MathJax buttons/hotkeys script
I've written a script that lets you insert dollar symbols automatically(via a keyboard shortcut or button) in the editor window on Stack Exchange sites that support MathJax (other sites have some extra buttons). Feel free to check it out.
Installation instructions and details here

Awesome, nice work Manishearth!

@JoshGitlin: Thanks! Unfortunately, you guys get only the bare-bones script and you don't get to see its full power (It's extremely useful when typing stuff on Chem.SE--the shortcuts preserve the flow of the page). You guys don't use math that much so I couldn't have any fun while configuring it for cogsci :( . ;-)
